# UI does not respond outside Application

Tags: jquery, ip

If `code.jquery.com` does not respond to a particular `IP`, how do I know if it is blocked?

[image: -]

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is not a true answer but why you dont use local file ?

Comment: @PekosoG I want to make sure that my public IP is disconnected from code.jquery.com

Comment: @The_Death_Raw
Changing to local file usage first. However, I would like to confirm whether my public IP has been blocked for future reference to the source via external URL.

Answer (score 0):

By your image link you have close to 1000 ms ping or 1 second ping to the site.

ping auto times out after 4 seconds.

So your issue is bad connection to the site and possibly [packet loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_loss).

You could try using the [ping](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490968.aspx) timeout flag `-w 10000` to increase the timeout to something longer.

It is not blocked or you would have no responses from your ping request.

[tracert](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491018.aspx) can help diagnose the issue as it pings each hop on your network and reports a ping for each 3 times.

Comment: If I check ping, it seems that my public address IP has been blocked at code.jquery.com 
I wanted to cancel the blocked IP, but I couldn't find a way, so I found stackoverfllow.

Comment: You are getting responses from your ping request therefore your IP is not blocked. If it was blocked I am not sure there is much of anything you could do about it.